# How do I add an AzureAD user to SQL Server for windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, azure-activedirectory

When users are logging in to a Windows 10 desktop with an Azure Active Directory account how do I add them as a user to SQL Server? Using the Search dialog from the Add Login dialog doesn't seem to find them using 'AzureAD\FirstnameLastname' or 'first.last@thedomain.com' format.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I couldn't find any users through the UI but I was able to add a login like this:

```
create login [AzureAD\FirstLast] from windows;
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!