# How to give file permissions to AzureAD user on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, azure, azure-activedirectory

I'm on a Win10 workstation that's joined to AzureAD like [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/05/28/azure-ad-join-on-windows-10-devices.aspx). How can I grant file permissions to an AzureAD user? When I try to use the File Properties > Security > Edit > Add dialog I can't find/select any users on the AzureAD domain, including the currently logged in user. Entering `AzureAD\FirstLast` and clicking Check Names gives this:

[image: error message]

In general this sort of thing seems to be a problem with AzureAD-joined accounts: windows appears to not know about them, e.g. when [adding them to SQL Server](https://superuser.com/questions/1009866/how-do-i-add-an-azuread-user-to-sql-server-for-windows-authentication). Or perhaps I just don't know the right way to refer to these users?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to Arni on [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/28951ca9-50a7-4432-af61-fb4f2c207b82/how-to-add-file-permissions-or-anything-else-for-azuread-users-on-azureadjoined-win10-machine?forum=WindowsAzureAD) for the answer:

> You can try the following command line. After adding an ACL entry, the
>   Security dialog will display the user and you can change the
>   permissions there.

```
CACLS "C:\YourPath" /T /E /G AzureAD\FirstLast:C
```

Comment: Being Administrator on my account the output on the console says `Access is denied` to: `CACLS "C:" /T /E /G AzureAD\UserName:F`

Comment: With `ICACLS "C:" /grant :r AzureAD\UserName:F` also fails...

Comment: @DavidDiez are you running the console window with elevated rights (as Administrator)?

Comment: @@Rory Yes, I am running the console with elevated rights

Comment: cacls is now deprecated. The equivalent icacls command is: 
`icacls "C:\yourpath" /t /grant azuread\FirstLast:M`

Comment: +1 Just had to say this worked perfectly, when other options failed. Just used the icacls variant instead though

Answer (score 12):

My cheating way: Add the Azure user to a unique local group
"net localgroup groupname domain\user /add"
Then give local group permissions

Comment: ... but first, create the local group with: `net localgroup GroupName /add`